# How to use map in R?

Tags: r, dictionary

I am working on map data structure in which i need to store key value pair.

```
 map[key1]<-value1
 map[key2]<-value2
 map[key3]<-value3
 map[key4]<-value4
```

I need to get value based on key. How can i implement this in R?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a list, because a simple vector constructed with `c` can't handle anything more than scalar values:

```
> map = c(key1 = c(1,2,3), key2 = 2, key3 = 3)
> map[["key1"]]
Error in map[["key1"]] : subscript out of bounds
```

why does this fail? because `map` is now:

```
> map
key11 key12 key13  key2  key3 
    1     2     3     2     3
```

use a `list` instead:

```
> map = list(key1 = c(1,2,3), key2 = 2, key3 = 3)
> map[["key1"]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

also dynamically extensible:

```
> map[["key99"]]="Hello You!"
> map
$key1
[1] 1 2 3

$key2
[1] 2

$key3
[1] 3

$key99
[1] "Hello You!"
```

Start with an empty `map=list()` if you are building one up.

Comment: If the map is going to be large and speed is an issue then using an environment instead of a list may help.  Environments are hashed for faster lookup, I think the list would be searched linearly until a matching key is found.  For small cases (and others) you will not notice a difference in the time, so a list is fine, but if the size and speed matter then environments can help.

Comment: How do you get the names (keys) of the list? `map.names` does not work.

Comment: `names(map)` - this is R, not python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a named vector:

```
map = c(key1 = 1, key2 = 2, key3 = 3)
map[["key1"]]
```

And you can easily add new ones:

```
map[["key4"]] = 4
> map
key1 key2 key3 key4 
   1    2    3    4
```

Comment: i need to do it dynamically. i am parsing one file so i cannot use fixed size map = c(key1 = 1, key2 = 2, key3 = 3)

Comment: You can add stuff dynamically, see my edit. If you want to use a very large map structure, you could choose to preallocate it. And by large I mean thousands or more.

Comment: This only works if the values are atomic. For anything more than that, use a list.